# jQuery - Get Total value of the next options based on identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

**HTML**

```
<option data-task-hours="100" value="1"> - Parent Task</option>
<option data-task-hours="50" value="2"> -  - Child task 1 </option>
<option data-task-hours="25" value="3"> -  -  - Child task 1.1</option>
<option data-task-hours="25" value="4"> -  -  - Child task 1.2</option>
<option data-task-hours="50" value="5"> -  - Child task 2</option>
```

**jQuery Code to fetch total value of selected next option(s):**

```
var selectedOption = $('#dropDownId option:selected')
var selectedOptionValue = selectedOption.data('task-hours');
var sum = 0;
selectedOption.nextAll().each(function(){
    if (sum < selectedOptionValue) {
        sum += $(this).data('task-hours');
    } else {
        sum = selectedOptionValue;
        return false;
    }
});
```

The code only works for parent task. If I add a sub-child i.e. `Child 1.1` with hours = 25, it won't allow. How could we break down Child Task hours i.e. `50` can further be break down to `25+25` and check if `Child task 1` has sub-childs `Child task 1.1` and `Child task 1.2`

Is there a better way to distinguish `parent and child task` which can be further break down to `sub-child task` ?

Comment: Add a `data-level` attribute? How are those `options` being generated? Server-side?

Comment: @ApulGupta That won't work in this instance as the HTML5 spec doesn't allow nested `optgroup`s

Comment: @RGraham using `data-level` attribute how can I get all succeeding rows i.e. `Parent having Child` and `Child having sub-child` ?

Answer (score 0):

I would add a data-parent-id on each item:

```
<option data-task-hours="100" data-parent-id="0" value="1"> - Parent Task</option>
<option data-task-hours="50" data-parent-id="1" value="2"> -  - Child task 1 </option>
<option data-task-hours="25" data-parent-id="2" value="3"> -  -  - Child task 1.1</option>
<option data-task-hours="25" data-parent-id="2" value="4"> -  -  - Child task 1.2</option>
<option data-task-hours="50" data-parent-id="1" value="5"> -  - Child task 2</option>
```

Comment: mkaatman: While adding `Child task 1.1` how can I know that `Child task 1` has a sub-child or not ?